# How do I view all work that a specific user has checked in?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tf-cli, tfvc

Another user has made several changes in different places throughout a specific project.

How do I see which files have been checked-in by a specific user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the command line issue:

> `tf history $/ProjectName /user:domain\user /recursive /noprompt`

That will list all the changesets of that user

Then issue:

> `tf changeset 12345 /noprompt`

To list all the changes in that changeset.

Currently I can't think of one command which will give you both. But you might be able to use Powershell or a custom console app that leverages the TFS Client Object Model to piece something together that does.

[image]

`tf.exe` can be found in the following folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio {VISUAL STUDIO VERSION}\Common7\IDE`. The easiest way to use it, is to open the command prompt using the "Visual Studio / Developer Command Prompt" item in the start menu that is created when you install Visual Studio.

[image]

As Tim Mentions, you can use the TFS Side Kicks to query this information as well. For Visual Studio 2010, this is still a stand alone application, for Visual Studio 2013 it nicely integrates into the Source Control Explorer context menu:

[image]

Comment: Sorry not so good with command line, I am getting "'tf' is not recognised" - Do I need to be in a specific directory to do this? How do I to the point where "tf history $/ProjectName /user:domain\user /recursive /noprompt" will work for me?

Comment: Just to note that in my circumstance, I didnt have to put in the domain part for the user in 'tf history $/ProjectName /user:domain\user /recursive /noprompt'. It seems in my circumstance it was added automatically.

Comment: So what worked for me was tf history . /user:FooB\Ben.Foo /recursive /prompt

Answer (score 2):

[tfs sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) using the history sidekick will give you a GUI version of what the user's touched.

Comment: Yes, that's right, the TFS Sidekicks provide a couple of great ways to query TFS from outside of Visual Studio. I hadn't used them for so long that I'd forgotten all about them. Thanks for the reminder.